# Diagonalization of matrix and how to use it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, svd

I got this diagonalizable matrix $ H = Q\Lambda Q^T$ which is actually a Hessian of the function used in finding the optimal parameter $\theta$ ($\mu$ is regularization parameter and it is a scalar, if it matters, know that this equation came from first order optimality condition $H(\theta - \theta^*) + \mu\theta = 0$):
$$\theta = (H + \mu I)^{-1}H\theta^*$$
What I don't understand here is how they come from using property of the diagonalizable matrix H to the next result $$\theta = (H + \mu I)^{-1}H\theta^* = Q(\Lambda + \mu I)^{-1}\Lambda Q^T \theta^*$$
I understand they start like this :
$$\theta = (H + \mu I)^{-1}H\theta^* = (Q\Lambda Q^T + \mu I)^{-1}Q\Lambda Q^T \theta^*$$
But from here I don't understand how they reduce it to last term in the equation goal I showed one equation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ is a Hessian, it is symmetric, so that $Q$ is orthogonal and $QQ^T=I$.

Because they have the same inverse, these matrices are equal:

$$\left[Q(\Lambda + \mu I )Q^T\right]^{-1} = Q(\Lambda + \mu I )^{-1}Q^T $$

So, starting with: $$\theta = (H + \mu I)^{-1}H\theta^*$$
we have
$$\begin{aligned} \theta &= (Q\Lambda Q^T + \mu QQ^T)^{-1}H\theta^*\\
&=\left[Q(\Lambda + \mu I )Q^T\right]^{-1}H\theta^*\\
&= Q(\Lambda + \mu I)^{-1} Q^TH\theta^*\\
&= Q(\Lambda + \mu I)^{-1} Q^T Q\Lambda Q^T\theta^*\\
&= Q(\Lambda + \mu I)^{-1} \Lambda Q^T\theta^*.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Last sentence resolved all my confusion, thanks a lot for that!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Moved the last sentence to the top.  Perhaps this flows better ...